# HTML Form Values don't push to JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sorting

Ok, so I am trying to push the value of an HTML form input to a JavaScript array. When I load the page and submit values through the form, it returns empty strings in the array. I don't understand why this is happening. Thank you for your help.

Relevant HTML:

```
<form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name1">Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control b" id="nameone">
                    <label for="pref1">Preferences: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control a" id="prefone"> </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name2">Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control c" id="nametwo">
                    <label for="pref2">Preferences: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control a" id="preftwo"> </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name3">Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control d" id="namethree">
                    <label for="pref3">Preferences: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control a" id="prefthree"> </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name4">Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control e" id="namefour">
                    <label for="pref4">Preferences: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control a" id="preffour"> </div>
                    <!-- ... -->
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="sbm">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Relevant JavaScript:

```
var table1 = [];
    var table2 = [];
    var table3 = [];
    var table4 = [];
    var names = [];
    var pref = [];

// ...

function namesdefine() {
        names.push(document.getElementById('nameone').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('nametwo').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('namethree').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('namefour').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('namefive').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('namesix').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('nameseven').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('nameeight').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('namenine').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('nameten').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('nameeleven').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('nametwelve').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('namethirteen').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('namefourteen').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('namefifthteen').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('namesixteen').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('nameseventeen').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('nameeighteen').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('namenineteen').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('nametwenty').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('nametwentyone').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('nametwentytwo').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('nametwentythree').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('nametwentyfour').value);
        console.log(names);
        var testvar = document.getElementById('nameone').value;
        console.log(testvar);
        console.log("Look here please");
    }
 document.getElementById('sbm').onclick = namesdefine();seat(document.getElementsByClassName('a').value);check();changeHTML();
    console.log(table1);
    console.log(table2);
    console.log(table3);
    console.log(table4);
    console.log("second call");
```

Answer (score 3):

You're calling the `namesdefine()` function when you assign to `.onclick`. You should be assigning the function to `.onclick`, so leave out the `()` after it.

```
document.getElementById('sbm').onclick = namesdefine;
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use:

```
document.getElementById('sbm').onclick = namesdefine;
```

Or

```
document.getElementById('sbm').addEventListener('click', namesdefine);
```

If you need to call them all, use this:

```
document.getElementById('sbm').onclick = function () {
    namesdefine();
    seat(document.getElementsByClassName('a').value);
    check();
    changeHTML();
}
```

And it's always a good practice to check for `null` after `getElementById()`

Comment: Thank you. It works but the changes disappear once the page reloads after I press the submit button. How can I keep this from happening?

Comment: Never Mind. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get your data in a loop.
You can use getElementByTagName or getElementByClassName.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    //Create array here arr.push(elements[i].value);
}
```

You can call that in your click function.
Hope that helps.